# When the is the constructor of the vector called in the following code?

Tags: c++

The following code can be compiled and run. I am wondering when the constructor of `v` is called. Is it called before the constructor of `A` is called? Also I am wondering whether the following code satisfies c++ standard.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A{
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    A(int b) { v.push_back(b); };
};

int main() {
    A a(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before the body of `A::A` is entered: _"..Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and __non-static data members__ is finished. ..."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: And since there is a second question here, which obviously is not answered in the duplicate - yes, this code is standard-complying.